# Special html chars appearing in raw form when I echo my variable

Tags: php

I import some text from an XML file and I trim it and replace multiple white spaces.

```
$var = $myxmltext;
$var = trim($var);
$var = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$var);
```

For some reason I get "raw html" like this when I echo it:

```
quot; or IÂ’ve instead of I've
```

Any ideas why?

Here is my trim function:

```
function mytrim($mytrim){
    $mytrim = utf8_decode($mytrim); 
    $mytrim = trim($mytrim);
    $rule1 = array(
        ",",    // virgula
        ".",    // punct
        "~",    // ~
        "_",    // underscore
        "-",    // liniuta
        ")",    // paranteza inchidere
        ":",    // doua puncte
        ">",    // mai mare
        "<",    // mai mic
        "!",
        "?",
        "*",
        "&"
    );
    $rule2 = array(
        ", ",   // virgula
        ". ",   // punct
        " ~ ",  // ~
        " ",    // underscore
        " - ",  // liniuta
        ") ",   // paranteza inchidere
        ": ",   // doua puncte
        " > ",  // mai mare
        " < ",  // mai mic
        "! ",
        "? ",   
        "* ",
        " & "
    );
    $mytrim = str_replace($rule1, $rule2, $mytrim);
    $rule3 = array(
        " .",   // punct
        " ,",   // virgula
        " ?",   // question mark
        " !",
        " *",
        " )"
    );
    $rule4 = array(
        ".",    // punct
        ",",    // virgula
        "?",    // question mark
        "!",
        "*",
        ")"
    );
    $mytrim = str_replace($rule3, $rule4, $mytrim);
    $mytrim = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$mytrim);
    return $mytrim;
}
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES); tried this but it did not work. I need something to reverse the process I believe

Comment: You see `quot;` is not actually a HTML entity, so using html special chars won't work. Also it seems the file has some encoding problem, probably not uft8: `IÂ’ve`

Comment: Thats what I am thinking also, and I think I'm left to use preg_replace for every entity

Comment: Well that's the second problem, if the file is this badly done there is no standardised method by which to preg_replace since `/(\w+;)/` could match actual text in your text. Sounds like you have a minefield of trouble from whatever/whoever made this file.

Comment: What does the original string look like?

Comment: Also what creates this file? And how do you read it?

Comment: Its an xml file from an affiliate site. I load it using simple_xml

Comment: Using $mytrim = str_replace('quot;', '', $mytrim); worked - but I cannot automate it since there are so many html problems

Comment: seems an encoding problem. try `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` before replace.

Comment: Can you slap the code in the question for a very basic iteration your doing and also var_dump the original string both in PHP and in the XML file as @PeeHaa said?

Comment: I would like that but the code contains adult content profiles. If you want to I can put a link to the problem page and delete it in a couple of minutes

Comment: LOL, why delete? Please, share!

Comment: To any admin, I will delete the link in a few minutes, hope is ok

Comment: Ah we are all adults here, but ok, I see the page and I am looking at it

Comment: I just added the var dump, with orange.

Comment: Yea I see the problem some one has ungratfully put a big fat space after every & to make your life harder

Comment: I may be doing this myself, I am trying to solve some punctuation problems also because some bios don't have spaces between words, etc. So in a way I may have caused it. Here is my punctuation function. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you run that before var_dumping? If not then it must be from the xml like that

Comment: Its before my rules, so it's from the xml, let me try a string replace replacing the '& ' to '&'

Comment: Ok I might have a pre_replace you can run on the xml string, try it out in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex before you do you stuff:

```
preg_replace('/(&)\s+(\w+;)/', '$1$2', $text);
```

Then do your business, lets see if that HTML encodes right now.

So what this will do is solve your main problem of HTML encoding by changing all:

```
& quote;
```

to:

```
&quote;
```

Be aware: This might not work exactly as expected so please test.

Of course as others say you can also utf8_decode/encode as well to get rid of those umlet characters.

### Edit

To solve the Ampersand problem try:

```
preg_replace('/&(?!\w+;)/', ' & ', $text);
```

So this will replace all & that is not in the form `&quote;` and give them a space either side.

Same as normal, test it first.

Comment: Your preg_replace worked, but I had to remove the & part from my trim function also, in order to make it work

Comment: @webmasters Ah kool, I thought I wrote my last comment a bit fast then but turns out I didnt :)

Comment: But, why does my trim function breaks the code? I used your preg replace before the trim function condition. So the html chars should be converted and the function should work on single "&"'s

Comment: @webmasters cos it breaks the & indiscrimantly targeting elements like `&quote;` which breaks HTML entity syntax to make `quote;`.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this without breaking? For example I have: hello I am john&I like cars. I need to put spaces before and after the &

Comment: @webmasters WHat does replacing the & actually do? Maybe you don't need it?

Comment: Any ideas how to do this without breaking? For example I have: hello I am john&I like cars. I need to put spaces before and after the &. Or someone adds text like this: hello this is a tex.without space after the stop sign which brakes an eventual limit function

Comment: I will try to fine tune the codes, ty for the help:) You have been more then helpfull

Comment: @webmasters Gklad to have helped, it's got on the right track anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that it is an encoding issue, XML files use UTF-8 by default, try using utf8_decode() before trim() and preg_replace()

```
$var = utf8_decode($myxmltext);
$var = trim($var);
$var = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$var);
```